# Specifying IP for Some Domainname

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl, net-http, curb

I am calling a number of apis of a web service hosted on a number of servers. Requests get routed to these servers at random through a load balancer. 
All these servers reside on my local network and I want one particular api call to go to one particular server. 
Since I don't want other requests to get affected, I am unwilling to put a host entry on the server hosting my app.
Can this be achieved through code?
I am coding in ruby and using net-http gem to make api calls.
Any implementation using curb gem is also welcome.

Thanks

-Azitabh

Comment: Just use the ip address in that api call.

Comment: Using the IP directly might not work if the Web Service is a named VHOST (which is the most common setup).

Comment: Mine is a named vhost as well. So using ip directly is ruled out.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to achieve what you want is to use a proxy with DNS Spoofing.

[Charles proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/tools/dns-spoofing/) does that but there might be other tools also.

Comment: This I guess will direct all requests to that domain name to the configured ip. What I want is a particular api call to go to a particular ip. Everything else should remain unperturbed.

Answer (score 0):

One way(on the same lines as suggested by systho) I can think of is to make the api call directly using the IP and create a vhost on the server which is listening directly on a separate port.

This will work for me purely because of the fact that I have access to the servers hosting the web service.